# Equation relating alternating magnetic field strength to induced voltage in search coil

Tags: electromagnetism, coil, magnetics, induction, magnetic-flux

I have a search coil (loop area A, N turns) placed normal to an alternating magnetic field with equation B(t)=Bp.sin(2.pi.f.t), B=field strength at time t, Bp=peak field strength, f=frequency, t=time. What is the equation to find the induced voltage in the search coil?
How would this change if the coil was at an angle to the normal?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I have a search coil (loop area A, N turns) placed normal to an
> alternating magnetic field (strength B, frequency f), what is the
> equation to find the induced voltage in the search coil?*

Assuming that the magnetic field flux density (\$B\$) is constant across the aperture of the search coil, you can calculate the the total flux entering the aperture of the search coil by multiplying \$B_{peak}\$ by the area of the search coil. This converts teslas to webers.

Then, given that the frequency is \$f\$, this defines the peak value of \$\frac{d\phi}{dt}\$ (assuming a sinewave).

It's then a simple matter of multiplying by the number of turns (\$N\$) to get the peak voltage. Assuming the applied field is sinusoidal, the RMS voltage is easily found.

> *How would this change if the coil was at an angle to the normal?*

Multiply the number derived from what I said above by \$\cos(\theta)\$ (where \$\theta\$ is the angle of the coil). In other words, an angle of \$\theta\$ less than 90 ° reduces the effective area of the coil to zero when at 0 °.

Comment: Thanks, so would this mean the equation is: V_peak=B_peakANw? (where w=2.pi.f)

Comment: That looks about right.

Answer (score 2):

.Generally Faraday's law of inductions tells us that \$ E_{mf} = -N\frac{d(\vec{B}\cdot\vec{n})}{dt}\$ if \$\vec{n}\$ is the vector normal to a surface \$ A(x(t),y(t)) \$.